# Expo-Doctor Failure: Native Module Compatibility Issue with @expo/config-plugins

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I encountered an issue while running `npx expo-doctor` in my Expo project directory. The warning about using cmd.exe on Windows is noted, but the primary concern is a native module compatibility problem, specifically with `@expo/config-plugins`. The detailed results indicate an expected package version of ~7.2.2, but the found version is @expo/config-plugins@7.3.1.

Expecting a successful diagnostic check, I aimed for a clean project health report with dependencies and configurations in order. Instead, the `expo-doctor` output unveiled warnings and errors, emphasizing the compatibility issue with `@expo/config-plugins`. The recommended solution is to upgrade dependencies using the invalid package versions.

My goal is to resolve this compatibility issue and align the project with the specified package versions. Your insights on addressing this matter will be immensely appreciated. Thank you!